# Hide the echo message when refresh the page

Tags: php, html, mysql

This error message appear in the sign up page when user input name was exit in the database.

```
<?php

include_once 'database.php';


if(isset($_POST['sign_up'])) {

    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
    $password = $_POST['txt_pwd'];
    $databasenam = $_POST['database_uname'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];

    $db_query = "CREATE DATABASE " . $databasenam . "";
    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $db_query)) {
        echo "<p class='error'> * This username was taken, try another please </p>";
    }
```

I want the echo message hide when user refresh the page.

Comment: Check about `$_SESSION`

Comment: I have no idea why you're creating an entirely new database when a user signs up, why do they get a whole database to themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused about your SQL query, are you creating a table for each username or is it one table with each username.

If it is one table with all the usernames and you are checking to see if that user name exist then i will be able to help you out but i just need some more information.

I was unable to comment instead of posting an answer due to my low rep

I find it odd that you would be creating a new database for each user

But to answer your question:
You could have a query like the following:

```
$sql = "SHOW DATABASES LIKE '$databasenam'";
$result =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if($result->num_rows) {
  echo "<p class='error'> * This username was taken, try another please </p>";
}
```

However if you want to check if that username exist in a table already then this a completely different approach.

Comment: yes, i'm trying to create database for each user. Are there many disadvantage in doing this?

Comment: @user yeah, plenty. It is indeed very rare that you need a database per user.

Comment: the above code checks to see if there is a database with that name 
but why do you need a database for every user?
i feel like you would have one database that will store the user details for all customers in one table, which will make it easier to search for the username

Comment: The idea of ​​a graduation project is an inventory management system that each user has many tables. I suspect that each user has a own database would be better
do you agree with me ?

Comment: no you would have one database with many tables
like one database 
then one table that holds the customer info
another table that may relate to inventory etc

Comment: When all user data is in one table
How will I know this stock for any user?
And when the user logs in, can I just make him show his stock data?
In the dashboard, how can I analyze only one user inventory data?

Comment: You could have one table just for the user which has a foreign key linked to another table that contains data about the stock or if all you need to know is the stock and thats it just include stock as a attribute. Also i believe i answered your original question so of youd like to mark it as correct.. im also happy to help with any other questions you have

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause with your `CREATE DATABASE` command.

You can try this modification to your code:

```
<?php

include_once 'database.php';


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" and isset($_POST['sign_up'])) {

    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
    $password = $_POST['txt_pwd'];
    $databasenam = $_POST['database_uname'];
    $email  = $_POST['email'];
    $cpassword = $_POST['cpassword'];

    $db_query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " . $databasenam . "";
    if(!mysqli_query($conn, $db_query)) {
        echo "<p class='error'> * This username was taken, try another please </p>";
    }
```